# Gerar números aleatórios com resultado total fixa em python

Tags: python

Preciso gerar 3 números aleatório e a soma desses tem que ser igual a 1.0.
segue a ideia mais ou menos, acredito que da forma que estou fazendo demoraria muito chegar a um retono..

```
import random

total = 1.0
x1= 0.0
x2= 0.0
x3= 0.0
while(x1+x2+x3)!=total:
  x1= random.uniform(0.1, 0.45)
  x2= random.uniform(0.1, 0.45)
  x3= random.uniform(0.1, 0.45)

print(x1, x2,x3)
```

Comment: Por que não gera apenas dois números aleatórios e faz o terceiro ser `x3 = total-x1-x2`? Assim garante que a soma sempre será `total` e que os três valores sejam *aleatórios*.

Comment: vou acatar sua idéia :)

Answer (score 2):

Conforme sugerido pelo Anderson [nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/393165/gerar-n%c3%bameros-aleat%c3%b3rios-com-resultado-total-fixa-em-python#comment773797_393165), você calcular apenas

```py
x3 = total - x1 - x2
```

---

Entretanto, note que ao mudar o cálculo de `x3` e manter os cálculos de `x1` e `x2` da maneira que está, o valor médio de `x3` seria de `E[x3] = E[total] - E[x1] - E[x2] = 1 - 0.55 = 0.45`<sup>[1]</sup>, e assim sendo, as variáveis definidas teriam valores aleatórios, mas suas [distribuições probabilísticas](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribui%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_probabilidade) seriam diferentes.

Na prática, isso significa que geralmente será sorteado valores maiores para `x3` do que para as outras variáveis.

---

Se esse comportamento for inconveniente, você pode calcular as três variáveis com

```
  x1= random.uniform(0.1, 0.45)
  x2= random.uniform(0.1, 0.45)
  x3= random.uniform(0.1, 0.45)
```

depois calcular seu somatório

```
  somatório = x1 + x2 + x3
```

para enfim obter variáveis

```
x1Modificado = x1/somatório

x2Modificado = x2/somatório

x3Modificado = x3/somatório
```

e assim a soma de `x1Modificado`, `x2Modificado` e `x3Modificado` será `1`.

---

<sup>[1] Valor obtido usando a fórmula da média da [distribuição uniforme](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribui%C3%A7%C3%A3o_uniforme): (1/2)*(b+a).</sup>